# Loop through Alamofire JSON Results in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a web service that returns the following JSON results about mobile devices:

```
{
  "devices": {
    "device": [
      {
        "model": "iPhone 6",
        "OS": "iOS 10"
      },
      {
        "model": "iPad Air",
        "OS": "iOS 9"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to loop through the results of this JSON and the results should be something like:

```
[iPhone 6, iPad Air]
[iOS 10, iOS 9]
```

So far all I have come up with is:

```
    for (_,_):(String, JSON) in json["devices"]["device"] {

 }
```

This will loop through the "devices" array but I am not sure how to then look through the dictionaries and grab the "model" values and then grab the "os" values.

**UPDATED: Revised question to be more clear with my goal and with what I have so far.**

Comment: Show us how you save data in an array.

Comment: I have:  var deviceArray: [AnyObject] = []

And then to add to it would be something like: deviceArray.append(test)

Answer (score 0):

I modelled your data as a dictionary and this seemed to work for me:

```
let dictionary = [
    "devices": [
        "device": [
            ["model": "ip6", "OS": "iOS10"],
            ["model": "ipad air", "OS": "iOS9"],
        ]
    ]
]
if let devices = dictionary["devices"], let deviceArray = devices["device"]  {
    for device in deviceArray {
        if let model = device["model"], let os = device["OS"] {
            print("\(model), \(os)")
            // Save your model and os to their respective arrays here
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: If the values are from Alamofire and assuming the return works then you would simply store the return value into the dictionary and do the same thing from above:

i.e.

```
guard let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
    print("Return result not in form [String: Any]")
    return
}
```

Comment: This hard codes the values into a dictionary. I need it to be dynamic since the JSON could return 3 devices or 40 devices.